# How do I treat chafing?

Tags: exercise, chafing, treatment

I believe that just about every sports athlete and fitness guru has run into this problem.  I've addressed already what to do to [prevent chaffing](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2319/how-do-i-prevent-chafing), but let's say that we didn't follow that.  What are some things that can be done to *treat* chafing?

Comment: Repetition of the same question http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2319/how-do-i-prevent-chafing/2321#2321

Comment: @Kirk Hammett - not really a dupe. One is for treatment, one is for prevention. It's a good separation as they have very different answers.

Answer (score 3):

I have found that using Desitin or other 'diaper rash' ointments helps to relieve the pain and swelling.  Apply to the affected area liberally and rub it in. I suggest an application of twice daily.

[image]

*WARNING: these rash ointments do have active ingredients and therefore make sure you are not allergic and discontinue use if skin gets worse. Be sure to follow the [directions precisely](http://www.desitin.com/how-to-treat-diaper-rash).*

You for sure want to make sure that your skin stops rubbing against the material that has caused the chaf.