# Humidity rashes and bumps between legs and upper tighs

Tags: running, pain, chafing

I live in Florida and it is very humid throughout the year. I wear loose clothes like shorts etc but even with that I get humidity rashes/bumps on my inner upper thighs. I am failing to understand what can I do in this scenario. Should I put some powder on that area to keep it dry or should I put some cream before I go out for running. Please help!

Comment: Do either of these answer your question? [Chafing prevention](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2319/how-do-i-prevent-chafing), or [Chafing Treatment](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2349/how-do-i-treat-chafing).

Comment: The problem is I don't understand if I need to put cream on it or keep is dry using some sort of powder. It is humidity rash.

Comment: Have you tried wearing tighter, sweat wicking fabrics? That should keep you dry and reduce skin-on-skin friction. I wouldn't recommend powder, but anti chafing cream may also help.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I wear really loose clothes. 90% of the time I am wearing shorts. Even if it is little humid outside, I get itching and rashes instantly.